# Prove that the area of a triangle is $\frac12 |a \times b| = \frac12 |b \times c| = \frac12 |c \times a|$

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles

I have a triangle $ABC$ where $\overrightarrow{AB} = \vec c, \overrightarrow{BC} = \vec a, \overrightarrow{CA} = \vec b$ and $\angle (\vec b, \vec c) = \alpha, \angle (\vec c, \vec a) = \beta, \angle (\vec a, \vec b) = \gamma$

I have to prove that the area of this triangle is given by $ \frac 12 |a \times b| = \frac 12 |b \times c| = \frac 12 |c \times a|$

I'm not sure where to begin but I don't think the following can be considered as a proof. 
 $\frac 12 |a \times b| = |a||b| \sin \gamma = |b||c| \sin \alpha = \frac 12 |b \times c|$

Comment: You mean a proof without using the sine rule?

Comment: I think it is a proof.

Comment: Observe that, for instance, $|b|\sin\gamma$ is the altitude of triangle $ABC$ though $A$, and apply the usual formula for the area of a triangle.

Comment: It is right, but how do you prove $|a||b|\sin \gamma = |b||c|\sin \alpha$? Also, do you know [the formula in this link](https://www.mathopenref.com/triangleareasas.html) for the area of a triangle? You are also missing a $\frac12$ in the last equality.

Comment: My bad, I forgot $\frac 12$ I can use sin rule. I'm just not that good with proofs so I'm never sure of what can be considered as a proof. I didn't know about $|b| sin \gamma$ for the altitude.
I can't see how I can prove $|a||b| sin \gamma = |b||c| sin \alpha$.

Comment: Notice that $|a\times b|$ is (geometrically) the area of the parallelogram of sides $a$ and $b$. To prove $|a||b|sin(\gamma)=|b||c|sin(\alpha)$ you can use the Law of Sines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are talking about triangles, I believe that the sine definition of a cross product is valid in this situation.

Suppose a triangle $\triangle ABC$ has side lengths $a,b$, and $c$ with angles $A,B,$ and $C$ opposite of each respective side $a, b, $ and $c$.

By the Law of Sines: $$\frac{\sin A}{a}=\frac{\sin B}{b}=\frac{\sin C}{c} $$

The cross product of two vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $$\vec{x}\times \vec{y}=||\vec{x}|| \cdot ||\vec{y}||\cdot \sin\theta $$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.

Area of $\triangle ABC$ is $$\frac{1}{2}ab\sin C$$

I suggest drawing a picture and manipulating the Law of Sines to see why they are equal and thinking of the sides of the triangle as two dimensional vectors.

Edit- Consider the following diagram:
[image]

We know that $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin C$ is the area of the triangle. By the Law of Sines, we can obtain $$b\sin A=a\sin B$$ $$c\sin B=b\sin C$$ $$c\sin A=a\sin C $$

We also know, if we let the sides of our triangle be vectors, that $$|a\times b| = ab\sin C$$ $$|a\times c|=ac\sin B $$ $$|b\times c|=bc\sin A$$

All that is left for you to do now is to just manipulate some of the above expressions and substitute some things using Area of $\triangle ABC =\frac{1}{2}ab\sin C$.

Comment: There's something I can't see. $\frac12 ab sin C$ give me the area of a triangle, but I use the law of sines to find an angle or a side.

Comment: @proxima Take two of three expressions from the law of sines and clearing denominators, for example, take $\frac{\sin A}{a}=\frac{\sin B}{b}$ and clear the denominators, same thing as cross multiplying.

Comment: Or don't bother with the Law of Sines: if you can prove the area is $\frac12|a \times b|$ then you can repeat the exact same proof for the other two cross products. Or recognize that all three formulas are just "half the magnitude of the cross product of two sides", so without loss of generality you can choose the two sides $a$ and $b.$

Comment: I'm still stuck. Both way I can't find a solution.
firstly, I honestly can't see how the law of sines [ $sin A * b = sin B * a$]  = $\frac12 absinC$.

I'm still stuck here.$\frac12 |a \times b\ |= \frac12(|a| |b| sin \gamma)$.
I made a triangle https://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html?vc=60&vx=5&vy=8&va=&vz=&vb=&angleunits=d&x=77&y=22
$\frac12(|a| |b| sin C) = 17.3$ and $bsinA = 4.94 = asinB$

Comment: @proxima I have added some edits. See if it is more clear to you now.